# Prevent Z-fighting of GN billboard instances?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, instances, z-fighting

Is there a way to prevent z-fighting of planar instances generated using Geometry Nodes?

Random distance doesn't space my planes far enough apart from each other.

Maybe there is a way to implement Poisson Disc distribution for the Z axis?

Or maybe there is a way to space instances *equally* on the Z axis?

The black spots are the result of planes z-fighting:

[image]

Here is the node setup, which I modified from [an answer by Hulifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265039/2952):

[image: Geometry Nodes setup for billboard particle style instances]

This area is probably the place to pay the most attention to:

[image: Nodes that determine height]

[image]

Comment: *"Or maybe there is a way to space instances equally on the Z axis?"* - yes there is, [sort](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264857/60486) the points on Z, then use *Map Range* to map their sorted index to a range of Z values (I think 0..0.7 in your case)

Comment: Thanks! Since we're dealing with points, and a random order is okay, is there an easy way to sort by vert index number? Maybe using ID?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I've figured out how to sort by point index along Z. Index node > Math (Multiply) > Combine XYZ (Z) > Set Position [Offset input]. Next I'll try it out with the whole node setup. Your hint about sorting helped me know what to search for and what to try. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What worked for me was to add spacing *to each point*, using the points' indices to target them - and then summing that with the random spacing that already existed. This way they are still staggered, but now include some minimum in-between padding.

[image: Geometry Nodes - random spacing plus index spacing]

The idea is that if you have two planes that are *really really* close together, even if you double/triple/etc the scale on Z, it may not affect those particular close neighbors enough to cure their z-fighting. But using the **Index** node it is possible to specify equidistant spacing. However we don't need to lose the desirable randomness - we can add the random and equidistant values together to get the best of both.

Problem solved:

[image]

Note that it doesn't take much spacing of the indices to eliminate the z-fighting. In my case a value of `0.0001` was enough.

**Reminder:** The **Clip Start** and **Clip End** also contribute to the appearance of z-fighting, and the clip settings are separate for the Viewport and the Camera. A broader start-to-end range is more likely to cause z-fighting, while a narrower one is less likely to.

Answer (score 4):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to achieve, but simple random value seems to help:

[image]

Else than that this seems to be a problem of z-buffer precision so no matter what you do if you have too many planes in the same region, some of them are going to get too close at some point no matter how you try to fit them, so the way I see it, you need to adjust viewport/camera clipping values to match the scene better or move the planes further apart.